# How can I add an Splash Screen to a PWA for iPad?

Tags: html, ipad, progressive-web-apps, splash-screen

I have tried this:

```
<link href="./ipad_splash.png" media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />
```

And i can't see my Splash Screen on my ipad.

Is there another way to add an splash screen?

Comment: Did you add this meta tag to your head tag?
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

Comment: Yes I added <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

Comment: Ok. Interesting... I'll drop this here then probably something there may help https://blog.expo.io/enabling-ios-splash-screens-for-progressive-web-apps-34f06f096e5c

Comment: Or here: https://www.simicart.com/blog/pwa-splash-screen/#For_iOS

Comment: Hi. I used the blog you sent me and it worked!!! Thank You so Much. it was really helpful

Comment: Glad to hear that the problem has been solved.